# Object cannot render as React Child (Error while using array.filer() method)

Tags: reactjs, redux, render

```js
const dataDisplay = this.state.allData.filter((item)=>{
        if(item.type==="Startup"){
            return(
                <div className="BlockForInvestor">
                    <div className="ImageDiv"><img src={item.link}></img></div>
                    <div className="ContentDiv">
                        <h1 className="Name">{item.name}</h1>
                    </div>        
                </div>
            );
        }
    });
```

Now rendering dataDislay produces error that object cannot be render as react child. Why is array.filter returning array of objects.

allData is an array of object where every object stores user data

Comment: Use this.state.allData.map instead filter

Comment: is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Filter return an array of elements which satisfied a condition in callback. You should use map method on this filtered array to convert these elements from objects to renderable React Elements

```js
const dataDisplay = this.state.allData
    .filter(item => item.type === 'Startup')
    .map((item)=>(
                <div className="BlockForInvestor">
                    <div className="ImageDiv"><img src={item.link}></img></div>
                    <div className="ContentDiv">
                        <h1 className="Name">{item.name}</h1>
                    </div>        
                </div>
            );
    });
```

Comment: Much more elegant than having to check within `map` using an `if` 

Comment: it may _seem_ more elegant but it's looping the array twice (or at least the items that matter will be looped over a second time). this may be a really bad decision with long lists at render cycles - so depends when you actually call the method.

Comment: You don't always need that performance. If you have a lot of conditions and not much data it's better to focus on readability. Don't optimize until you don't have to